# I encountered some issues regarding C#/blazor method invocations

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I create 2 service class.I want to use ServiceA to call ServiceB, but the application throws an error on startup. When I remove the reference to ServiceB, the application starts successfully.Can someOne give me a help, I am a C# beginner. thanks..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U0d1.png)

```
///service A

 public interface IArcNoRuleService
    {
        public void AddRule(ArcNORule rule);
        public List<ArcNORule> SelectRules();
    }

    public class ArcNoRuleService : IArcNoRuleService
    {
        private readonly IFreeSql _fsql;

        private readonly IArcNORuleSectionService _arcNORuleSectionService;

        public ArcNoRuleService(IFreeSql fsql, ArcNORuleSectionService arcNORuleSectionService)
        {
            _fsql = fsql;
            _arcNORuleSectionService = arcNORuleSectionService;
        }
}



/// service  B


 public interface IArcNORuleSectionService
    {
        public void AddRuleSection(ArcNORuleSection rule);

        public void UpdateRuleSections(List<ArcNORuleSection> sections);
    }

    public class ArcNORuleSectionService : IArcNORuleSectionService
    {

        private readonly IFreeSql _fsql;

        public ArcNORuleSectionService(IFreeSql fsql)
        {
            _fsql = fsql;
        }

        public void AddRuleSection(ArcNORuleSection rule)
        {
            _fsql.Insert<ArcNORuleSection>().AppendData(rule).ExecuteIdentity();
        }
}

/// blazor  startup

 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Authentication && Cookie
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();


            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddSingleton<IFreeSql>(sp => IntegPack.FSQL);
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddAntDesign();
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(sp.GetService<NavigationManager>().BaseUri)
            });
            services.Configure<ProSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ProSettings"));
            services.AddAntDesign();
            services.AddScoped<IChartService, ChartService>();
            services.AddScoped<IArcNORuleSectionService, ArcNORuleSectionService>();
            services.AddScoped<IArcNoRuleService, ArcNoRuleService>();
      
 
        }
```

I apologize if this is a basic question, but I don't have much knowledge about c#/blazor...

Comment: See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-7.0#avoid-ihttpcontextaccessorhttpcontext-in-razor-components) about using IHttpContextAccessor in Blazor. Summary: don't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service is registered against the interface as:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IArcNORuleSectionService, ArcNORuleSectionService>();
```

So you can't inject it like this:

```cs
public ArcNoRuleService(IFreeSql fsql, ArcNORuleSectionService arcNORuleSectionService)
```

You're using it correctly:

```cs
private readonly IArcNORuleSectionService _arcNORuleSectionService;
```

So inject it as you've registered it:

```cs
public ArcNoRuleService(IFreeSql fsql, IArcNORuleSectionService arcNORuleSectionService)
```